# What holds for invertible matrices?

Tags: matrices

Determine which of the formulas hold for all invertible $n x n$ matrices $A$ and $B$

1. $A+A^{-1}$ is invertible
2. $(ABA^{-1})^7 = AB^7A^{-1} $
3. $(A+B)(A-B) = A^2-B^2 $
4. $(A+A^{-1})^8=A^8+A^{-8} $
5. $A^9$ is invertible
6. $AB=BA$

I've solved them and I think 2 and 5 are the only ones that hold, is this right?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It seems correct indeed

> 1. $A+A^{-1}$ is invertible

- just consider $A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

> 2. $(ABA^{-1})^7 = AB^7A^{-1} $

- true by inspection

> 3. $(A+B)(A-B) = A^2-B^2 $

- $(A+B)(A-B)=A^2-AB+BA+B^2$ and see $6.$

> 4. $(A+A^{-1})^8=A^8+A^{-8} $

- $(A+A^{-1})^2=A^2+2I+A^{-2}\ldots$

> 5. $A^9$ is invertible

- $A^9A^{-9}=I$

> 6. $AB=BA$

- just consider $A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\quad
     B=\begin{bmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$